# Integration testing play framework using custom header in a request

Tags: scala, testing, playframework

I want to write tests to our project. The server must response other things if the Accept header and the Accept-Language and some other stuffs changeing.
We are using collaboration tools in the startup so I want to run a test against an url:port and not mocking it. I want it to go through on the full http stack if its viable (or at lest like the below example).

My main question is: How to write a test where I can fully parametrize the requests and can send against a web-server.

I write a working test like:

```
"returns valid json" in new WithBrowser {
  browser.goTo("http://" + AppConf.getString(AppConf.MOBILE_CLIENT_URL) + ":" + AppConf.getString(AppConf.MOBILE_CLIENT_PORT) + "/version")
  Json.parse(browser.pageSource)
  browser.pageSource must contain("\"communicationVersion\"")
  browser.pageSource must contain("4")

}
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution:

Extends from PlaySpecification instead of Specification, import play.api.libs.ws.WS and try it like:

```
"returns valid json" in new WithServer {
  val f = WS.url(mobileUrl + "/version").withHeaders(("Accept", api.acceptedAcceptHeader)).get()
  val r = await(f)
  r.json
  r.body must contain("\"communicationVersion\"")
  r.body must contain("4")
}
```

Other problems may come in, like run the tests NOT paralell, but the answer to the question is this.